# Generalization of the geometric series to multiple variables using Lyndon words

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series, geometric-series, lyndon-words

The following claim can be found, without proof, in *A Formula for the Determinant of a Sum of Matrices* by Reutenauer and Schützenberger, (I am paraphrasing):

> In the algebra of noncommutative power series with indeterminates from a set $A$ with integer coefficients, we have,
> $$
> (1 - a_1 - \ldots - a_k)^{-1} = \prod_{l} (1 - l)^{-1},
> $$
> where the product is taken over all [Lyndon words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) in decreasing order.

Here, $A$ is a finite totally ordered set $A=\{a_1, \ldots, a_k\}$ satisfying $a_1 < \ldots < a_k$, whereas $l$ stands for a Lyndon word, and the product is taken over **all** Lyndon words. In particular, the right-hand side is an infinite product.

**My question is: how can one prove this fact?**

It is easy to see that when $A$ is a singleton set $A = \{a_1\}$, the fact above reduces to the geometric series. However, I do not see how to generalize the geometric series to multiple variables.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand, but isn't this just the same fact as the uniqueness of the standard factorisation of a string as a product of Lyndon words?

Comment: In the sources I have found, these two facts are claimed to be equivalent. However, I do not see how the uniqueness of Lyndon-factorizations implies the equation above.

Answer (score 0):

[Let me try it as an answer: if it's shot down I will remove it.]

The terms of the (formal) expansion of the LHS are exactly the words on the (ordered) alphabet $A$.

The terms of the (formal) product/expansion of the RHS are exactly the concatenations of Lyndon words in non-increasing order.

By the Chen–Fox–Lyndon theorem (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_factorisation#Chen%E2%80%93Fox%E2%80%93Lyndon_theorem)) each term on the LHS corresponds to precisely one term on the RHS.