# Determinant of a sum of matrices using Lyndon words

Tags: power-series, determinant, characteristic-polynomial, lyndon-words

In the paper *A Formula for the Determinant of a Sum of Matrices* by Reutenauer and Schützenberger, the authors show a way of computing the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_k$ in terms of the coefficients of the characteristic polynomials of the individual matrices $X_1, X_2, \ldots, ... X_k$. (Here all matrices are square and have the same size.)

The proof involves the following identity that I am trying to understand.
$$
\det \left( 1 - X_1 - \ldots - X_k \right) = \prod_l \det \left( 1 - l \right),
$$
where the product runs over all [Lyndon words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) $l$ in the alphabet $\{X_1, \ldots X_k\}$. In particular, the right-hand side is an **infinite product**. The proof involves the algebra of power-series. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196587/generalization-of-the-geometric-series-to-multiple-variables-using-lyndon-words) a related question about that proof.)

I am trying to understand how this is even possible. On the left-hand side of the equation, we have a polynomial, with a finite set of roots. On the right-hand side we have the product of infinitely many polynomials, and thus infinitely many roots (in general).

I have tried understanding this formula using a limit of the right-hand side. Define $p_n = \prod_{l \in L_n} \det \left( 1 - l \right)$, where $L_n$ is the set of Lyndon words of up to length $n$. Then, we can write
$$
\det \left( 1 - X_1 - \ldots - X_k \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n.
$$
However, I don't think this interpretation is correct because of the following. Take an arbitrary Lyndon word $l_0$ and let $z$ be a root of $\det (1 - l_0)$. Then, $p_n(z) = 0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. This would imply that each of the roots of each of the polynomials in the product are roots of $\det \left( 1 - X_1 - \ldots - X_k \right)$.

The only way that I can make sense of all of the above is that one of the following must be true:

1. Each of the roots of $\det \left( 1 - X_1 - \ldots - X_k \right)$ appears infinitely many times as a root of the polynomials $\det\left( 1 - l \right)$. This seems highly non-trivial and I cannot find a proof of it.
2. I am using the wrong definition of limit. Perhaps I am using the wrong topology in the ring of power series.

Any help in making sense of this formula is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a root of the determinant?

Comment: In the one-dimensional case (which is what our other question is about, except there you are looking more sensibly at the inverses of these expressions) you can easily check that the first few terms are correct. I think that to get all the terms you've got to describe the factorisations of each monomial in terms of Lyndon words and check that each monomial comes up the same number of times on each side. I don't see how limits help here, presumably the only sensible topology is the one generated by monomials of a given weight.

Comment: Ah I see where I may have been vague. By root of the determinant I mean the case where the identity is applied to compute $\det \left( 1 - t X_1 - t X_2 \right)$ which is of course the characteristic polynomial of the sum $X_1 + X_2$.

Comment: I thought of the limit approach by focusing on the fact that both sides of the equation are just functions of $t$ (again in the case of computing $\det \left( 1 - t X_1 - t X_2 \right)$). The convergence of the limit should be pointwise, no?

Comment: Leo, you are defining your limit in terms of your $p_n$, so *that* limit is in terms of weights of the monomials. As to your introduction of $t$ you are talking about the characteristic polynomial of $(X_1+X_2)^{-1}$ and I am finding it difficult to reconcile the LHS and RHS.

Answer (score 1):

I think that intuition is not a good guide when dealing with infinite products, even infinite products of polynomials. Just because $\alpha$ is a root of $p_0(X)$ this does not mean that $\alpha$ is a zero of $\prod_{n=0}^\infty p_n(X)$.

So (I use your comment) let us look at
$$
\det (1-t(X_1+\dots+X_n)=\prod_{\ell} \det(1- t^{w(\ell)}\ell)\tag{*}
$$
where the product runs over all Lyndon words, and $w(\ell)$ is the total degree of $\ell$.

Let us look at what your argument is saying in the simplest non-trivial case, the one where $n=2$, where the dimension of the underlying space is $1$, and where $X_1=X_2=1$. That is, we are looking at
$$
1-2t=\prod_{\ell}(1-t^{w(\ell)}).\tag{**}
$$.

This really is true: let's verify the first few terms. The Lyndon words on $X,Y$ are  $X,Y,XY, X^2Y,XY^2,\dots$ so the RHS of $(**)$ is
$$
(1-t)(1-t)(1-t^2)(1-t^3)(1-t^3)
$$
to degree 3; simplifying
$$
1-2t+O(t^4).
$$

However it is surely the case that $t=1$ is a root of every "factor" on the RHS, whereas the only root of the LHS is $t=\frac{1}{2}$.

Your related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196587/generalization-of-the-geometric-series-to-multiple-variables-using-lyndon-words) (which is answered by the uniqueness of the standard factorisation of a monomial into Lyndon words) allows us by taking inverses to prove $(*)$ without the determinants. Using the fact that $\det$ is multiplicative, and that it is continuous in the $t$-adic topology we will get a proof of $(*)$.

Comment: Thank you, this does start to clarify some things. Can you say more about the "$t$-adic topology"? How does that come into play here?

Comment: It's like the $p$-adic topology but the "prime" is $t$. We measure the closeness of $f$ and $g$ by how many powers of $t$ divide $f-g$.